# org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansException: Unable to instantiate class : org.apache.webbeans.web.context.WebContextsService

Tags: java, spring, apache, primefaces, nosuchmethoderror

SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener
org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansException: Unable to instantiate class : org.apache.webbeans.web.context.WebContextsService
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansContext.createInstance(WebBeansContext.java:431)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide more context and information after reading that. Dumping a stack trace and expecting an answer is not going to give you one.

Comment: For a start, we need the complete stacktrace, including the nested exceptions.